# Render quasar components that came from outside with fetching, onMounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, quasar-framework, quasar

I want to fetch data from my CMS and render Quasar Framework components inside of it in [Quasar Cli](https://quasar.dev/start/quasar-cli)

In quasar.config.js -> build:

```
extendViteConf(viteConf, {}) {
                viteConf.resolve.alias.vue = "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js";
            },
```

Boot file:

```
export default boot(({ app }) => {
    child_app = createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                message: "",
            };
        },
    });
    child_app.use(Quasar, {
        plugins: {}, // import Quasar plugins and add here
    });

    child_app.config.globalProperties = app.config.globalProperties;

    const { reload, ...appContext } = app._context;
    Object.assign(child_app._context, appContext);
});
```

Getting this error:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:40 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: q-carousel-slide
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <App>
```

I tried adding this but then, there is no rendering in the end;

```
child_app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = (tag) => {
        return tag.startsWith("q-");
    };
```

Only working solution I found is using [Quasar UMD](https://quasar.dev/start/umd) for mounted data :-/

I would prefer preventing double loading vue and quasar if possible.